# Encoding problem with Eclipse and running Windows 10 on Virtualbox

Tags: c++, eclipse, encoding, windows-10, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox on a mac to run Windows 10.

I installed

*openjdk version "12"
MinGW-W64 8.1.0
eclipse IDE Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)*

I can start eclipse normally and select workspace, but when I create a new c++ project, select c++ managed build, choose the hello world project with tool chain:

**Mingw gcc**, create it and try to look at the test.cpp in src it just shows me this error:

> Character encoding "Cp65001" is not supported by this platform.

*(I also get this error if I import other files)*

I can choose to set encoding, but when I choose something there, for example `UTF-8` it shows me the Hello World program but tells me that he cant resolve the symbol std, `cout` and `endl`.

I can build the project but if I try to run it, it gives me this error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Creating console for
>   C:\Users\Kai\eclipse-workspace\e\Debug\test.exe (21/04/2020, 18:00)".
>   Cp65001

I also get this error if I not change the encoding.

I also reinstalled Windows, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you use ASCII for source files?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What does "try to look at the test.cpp in src" actually mean?

Comment: It just means, that I click on the source file, where the hello world program is in.